# website to use yahoo account to login via openid connect

Tags: openid-connect

I am new to openid and oauth. I want to allow users to use yahoo or google account to login in the website. I think I can use Open ID Connect to accomplish this task? https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/
However, I look at many websites, and I cannot find a website is using Yahoo account to login. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

I think Yahoo is less popular than Google/Facebook for social login as the popularity of Yahoo has fallen over the years.

The redirect url is where you want the tokens to be sent to after successfull authentication. It is not the page the user will see, intead its a URL to your OpenIDConnect handler that will take the tokens and then create a session from those tokens. After that the browser will be redirected to the page you want the user to goto after successfull login.

See this picture, so the /signin-oidc is an enpoint that is your redirecURl in OpenIDConnect.

[image]

in Yahoo, you would also need to register the redirect url and it must match the redirectUrl parameter in the initial request (This is a security feature).

So based on my picture, you would register https://example.com/signin-oidc as your redirect url and use it in your authentication request.

See this Yahoo page about [OpenID Connect](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/)

Comment: I followed https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html very closely, but I keep getting error on "Developers: Please specify a valid request and submit again."

Comment: `var authorizationUrl = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth'
            + '?client_id=' + '<my client id>'
            + '&redirect_uri=' + '<redirect url>'
            + '&response_type=code'
            + '&scope=openid'
            + '&nonce=oGt3LhO'`

Comment: what does your redirect url look like? it includes http(s)? also you might need to encode it properly (urlencoding).

Comment: thanks Tore. I did already using url encoding like `redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.msn.com` but still failed. I am so frustrated and I wonder if Yahoo is still supporting OpenID Connect??

Comment: Hi Tore, is redirect_url supposed to be the authenticated URL (the URL to go after logging in)? The documentation says redirect_url is the URL after a user successfully authorizes an application, the authorization server will redirect the user back to the application with either an authorization code or access token in the URL. But it doesn't say if the URL should be authenticated or not?

Comment: I hope my updated answer makes my answer acceptable. PS ,